# Bamboo build variable outside Bamboo

Tags: gruntjs, jira, bamboo

My knowledge of Bamboo is pretty limited.  I have a grunt task that Bamboo needs to run, which works fine.

Currently Bamboo is tied to Jira but it would be nice if Bamboo could read something from Jira, and take that information and change the parameter when building.

Is this possible?  Any other solutions that may work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variables to bamboo from jira postfunction using the Bamboo CLI(bobswift plugin) by triggering the Bamboo build from the Jira itself:

`bamboo --action queueBuild --build "ZBAMBOOCLI3334667-checkout1" --wait --timeout 90 --field1 "exitCode" --value1 "0"`

This project `ZBAMBOOCLI3334667-checkout1` would be triggered and the bamboo variable `bamboo_exitCode` would hold the value of "0" in it.

You can pass extra parameters with this approach. `--field2` and `--value2` combination.

You can refer the CLI page for various tasks:
https://bobswift.atlassian.net/wiki/display/BCLI/Examples